# How to convert RTF (with images) to html in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, base64, rtf

I would like to make it possible to paste a text with images from Word to a html page. The `paste` clipboardData has a `text/rtf` item in it. I would like to convert this RTF data to html, and convert the images in it to base64 encoded images.

I was unable to find a js package, which can handle images too.
There is a project called [rtf2html](https://github.com/Novlr/rtf2html), but I am not able to use it, because the lack of documentation, and my lack of knowledge about RTF.

If there are no libraries for this task, then could you please give me some hints on how to write it using rtf2html

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score -2):

See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667658/how-to-convert-richtext-rtf-document-with-images-into-html-in-delphi?rq=1).  It mentions that you can open an RTF file in MS Word and then save the file with its image in an HTML format.  I tried it just now and was able to open the RTF-converted-to-HTML file in Google Chrome.  If you need to automate this, you should be able to do so using Visual Basic for Applications (it ships with MS Office).